# How to open a URL in Chrome, AND if is open in the background or minimized, bring it to front

Tags: c#

I have this command:

```
Process.Start(@"Chrome.exe", "http://192.168.1.2/url.aspx");
```

With this, I can open chrome with an URL, but if the application is already open, this command open a new tab, and I want to avoid this.

I want something like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventsArgs e)
{
    if(/*chrome is open*/)
    {
        //bring chrome to front and show the already opened tab;
    }
    else
    {
        //open a new window with url;
        Process.Start(@"Chrome.exe", "http://192.168.1.2/url.aspx");
    }

}
```

What should I do?

Comment: @HereticMonkey The code shown in that thread doens't work for me, Maybe because chrome?

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279461/1797425) about this...

Comment: [Edit] your question to show how you implemented the answer(s) of the question, and how it didn't work for you.